# How do I get the width/height of a 2d array being pointed to with my pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

If I have this reference variable:

```
float* image
```

How can I get the length of this image in C? The `length = (width * height)` but how can I get this value?

Comment: so how can I determine its length, no ways?

Comment: @devn: you have to keep the length together with the pointer.

Comment: no, I dont, I just get a reference by calling: analyse(float *image)

Comment: My home address is at 167, how long is my street? That is pretty much what you are asking. Which lib does that analyse function come from? We'll be able to help you knowing that.

Comment: Then whoever wrote `analyse` is storing the lengths behind the scenes for you (?)

Comment: Does the pointer contain the raw image data? Then you might be able to infer it from the data that the pointer points to, but not from the pointer itself.

Comment: And by the way, you don't have reference variable, but a pointer variable.

Comment: @Hannesh more accurately, the lat/long of the n/w corner of my property is x/y, how much property do I own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float * image
```

Simply points at a single float. It can also be used with array syntax -- ie `image[n]` to get the nth float from the location of image. People will use pointers and malloc to create a dynamic array of floats. However, there's no information associated with the size stored with the data itself. That's a detail the coder has to care about in C. Often in these kinds of cases in C when you're passed such a pointer in a function, you're also passed an accompanying size, ie:

```
void Foo(float* image, size_t numFloatsInImage)
```

It sounds like though that `image` might point to a block of contiguous memory treated as a 2d array. That is something with a width and height. So instead of strictly a numberOfFloats you might have something like this "3x3" image:

```
    image ->  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
              0  0  0  1  1  1  2  2  2
```

There's a total of 3x3 == 9 floats here with the first 3 corresponding to row 1, the next 3 row 2, and the last one as row 4. This is simply a single dimensional array used to represent 2d data.

Like I said before, this is a detail of how you've decided to use the language and not a part of it. You'll have to pass along the width/height with the pointer for safe use:

```
void Foo(float* image, size_t width, size_t height)
```

You can also avoid this by simply creating a struct to store your image, being sure to always initialize/maintoin the width and height correctly

```
 struct
 {
     float* image; // points to image data
     size_t width;
     size_t height;
 };
```

then always pass around the struct to functions like foo

Another trick could be to overallocate float to store the width and height in the buffer itself:

```
 float* image = malloc(width*height + 2);
 image[0] = width;
 image[1] = height;
 // everything past image[2] is image data
```

In any case, there's these and many other implementation specific ways to store/pass this data. Whoever is giving you this pointer should be telling you how to get the length/height and telling you how to use the pointer. There's no way C can figure out how it's being done, its an implementation decision.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `image` points to some data structure describing the dimensions of the image, you generally can't find the size in a predictable and safe manner. If you try, you'll most likely corrupt and/or crash the program. If `image` points to raw pixel data, you'll have to get the size along with this pointer from wherever you get the data.

Answer (score 1):

A plain pointer by itself won't tell you the size of the buffer it points to.  Unless the first element somehow encodes the size of the buffer, or there's a sentinel value at the end (similar to how strings are implemented), then that information *has* to be provided separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, if all you have is a pointer to a `float`, there's nothing which can tell you the size of the image from just that.